# GUI tool for viewing Neo4j database

Tags: neo4j

Is there a GUI tool which allows you to look at the contents of the Neo4j database visually.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The easiest is to start the neo4j server and view your graph via the webadmin: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tools-webadmin.html

Comment: We have used Cytoscape (http://www.cytoscape.org/) to render the graph based on our need and it is good.

Comment: The page doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 21):

[Gephi](http://gephi.org/) can connect to Neo4j databases, and offers a very powerful visualisation platform, albeit with a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: It's nice, but I tried it with a the huge musicbrainz db and crashes.

Answer (score 4):

There is a new solution to explore the content of a Neo4j graph database using a web browser: http://linkurio.us/

It allows you to search nodes by properties, inspect nodes, expand neighborhood in a click...

Disclamer: I'm co-founder of Linkurious and Gephi.

Comment: can Linkurious be used to visualize your cpyher query output on web applications as well?

Answer (score 4):

[Neoclipse](http://eclipse.neo4j.org/) is a great tool. Also take a look [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neoclipse).

Comment: Neocliepse is or was.. the best free opensource tools.
It's pity that it looks abandonned : (

Answer (score 4):

You might consider our application, [movies.graphalchemist.com](http://movies.graphalchemist.com/) for a demo.

We typically deploy our solution in a business intelligence scenario, however feel to reach out if you find it a good fit for your use case.

The other applications mentioned work was well, and we use some of them for specific things internally...

Answer (score 2):

Using it's own web interface is best.

Comment: run your neo4j instance then go to http://localhost:7474 
if you are running neo on a remote machine, create an ssh tunnel on your local machine