# How to visualize Neo4J node relationships?

Tags: neo4j, visualization

Given node relationships

- A "knows" B
- B "likes" C
- C "works at" X

Coupled with a few lines of Neo4J, is there a way i can export this into JPG or any other image?

**A more generic question - given relationships between nodes, what would be most straightforward way to create a diagram visually depicting them?**

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814336/gui-tool-for-viewing-neo4j-database/10821319#10821319 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060855/visualizing-graph-database?

Comment: Apart from the links mentioned, Gephi is a good option (https://gephi.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also view the data in the Neo browser
http://localhost:7474/
Start your local neo4j instance then go to the url or the url of the remote machine running neo4j (if open)
If your remote neo is on a private IP so that the browser is not open to the public you need to tunnel by

```
ssh -L 7474:[neo4j_private_IP]:7474 user_name@[neo4j_public_IP]
```